# Why do we say the group of order $p^3$ is not always abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For any integer $n$, there is a cyclic group $\Bbb Z(n)$.
So for any integer $n$ there is always an abelian group $G$.
So why we say the group of order $p^3$ is not always abelian?

Comment: Well, for a concrete example the Quaternion group of order $8 = 2^3$ is not abelian even though there *is* a cyclic group of order $8$.  Not every group of a given order falls into the same isomorphism class.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we can speak about "the" cyclic group of order $p^3$ (up to isomorphism). However, this does not mean that there aren't *other*, **non-cyclic** groups of that same order.

Since there's more than one isomorphism class of groups of order $p^3$, there is no single  "the" group of order $p^3$ to talk about.

Comment: So we see for any integer there always an abelian group.

Comment: From this we first decompose the  order of the  group and then use The Fundamental th of finite abelian groups we can find how many non-isomorphic groups (upto isomorphism) for the  any integer value n.

Comment: @avijitkundu:  at least one.  For four elements there is $\Bbb Z_4$ and the Klein group.  They are distinct and both are abelian.  For primes $p$  there is only one group, $\Bbb Z_p$, which is abelian. The direct product of abelian groups is abelian, so for composites there are more.  There may also be non-abelian groups of the same order.

Comment: @avijitkundu: Careful, using FToFAG you only get the number of non-isomoprphic *abelian* groups of order $n$. But also, this seems unrelated to your original question.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

You can't speak about *the* group of order $n$, because given $n\in\Bbb N$ there can be more than one group of that order.

If $n=p$ is prime, then (up to isomorphism) there exists exactly *one* group: $C_p$ (or $\Bbb Z_p$ if you prefer), which is the cyclic group of order $p$ (it's easy to prove).

In other cases it's often difficult to know how many non isomorphic groups of a given order $n$ there exist.

However the case $n=p^3$ is completely solved: there is a classification of finite groups of order $p^3$ (not only of order $8$).

Three of them are abelian: $C_{p^3}$, $C_{p^2}\times C_p$ and $C_p\times C_p\times C_p$.

The remaining two are not abelian (they are expressed as semidirect product).

If $n=8=2^3$ the non abelian groups are the quaternion group $Q_8$ and the dihedral group of the square $D_4$.